# IBM Bluemix container - Refreshing cf tokens - Unauthorized failure

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I setup 'ice' on my mac as per instruction in Bluemix docs.
I can successfully run 'ice login':

```
API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Username> XXXXXX@XXX.XXX

Password> 
Authenticating...
OK

API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.23.0)
User:         XXXXXX@XXX.XXX
Org:          XXXXXX@XXX.XXX
Space:        dev
Authentication with container cloud service at https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v2/containers completed successfully
You can issue commands now to the container service

Proceeding to authenticate with the container cloud registry at registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
WARNING: login credentials saved in /Users/giovanni/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded
```

but when I issue any other 'ice' command I receive an error. 
E.g. 'ice images':

```
Refreshing cf tokens
Unauthorized failure
```

Any advice on where to look for logs or what's the issue?

Cheers, Giovanni

Comment: I found out that before using Containers in Bluemix the account needs to be enabled. To do that it's necessary to go to Blumix UI and create a container. The creation won't happen but an approval process is fired.
I am now waiting to get my account enabled. 
I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, the issue appears to be one of not being authorized to access the beta IBM Containers offering. We have just enabled all users queued from yesterday for the beta, so you should be authorized to access the beta service now.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I confirm that after trying to create a container using Bluemix UI (website) and once received a confirmation email that I was authorised to use Container, 'ice' commands started working.
e.g.

```
$ ice images

Image Id                             Created              Image Name                                                      

d0feae99-b91d-4ce3-bcb4-6128886f6968 Mar 24 03:44:59 2015 registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty:latest
74831680-1c9c-424e-b8ea-ceede4aa0e40 Mar 24 03:41:24 2015 registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
```

Cheers, Giovanni